# conditional woocommerce checkout validation depending on product tag in cart

Tags: validation, woocommerce, checkout

for products with a special product tag I'd like to setup another validation of the address fields in the woocommerce checkout.
So my product tag id is 199, when a product with this tag is in the cart, the validation should be different. I get this going to work, but my code affects also the "normal" checkout where I want to work the validation as usual. It produces some extra fields.

Maybe someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'schwinn_validation', 10, 1 );
    function schwinn_validation( $address_fields ) {
    $schwinn_cart=WC()->cart->get_cart();


    foreach( $schwinn_cart as $cart_item ){

        $product_array = $cart_item['data'];

        //echo $product_array->tag_ids[0];
        $product_tags_incart=$product_array->tag_ids[0];

        // wenn das Produkt mit tag id 199 getagt ist, wird eine andere validation durchgeführt

        if($product_tags_incart == 199 ){

        $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_first_name']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_last_name']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_city']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;

        return $address_fields;
    
        };
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show some capture of the normal checkout and the special checkout please?

Comment: this is how the 'normal' address fields look like https://neonschwarz-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/f_pernleitner_bretz-austria_at/ESluKSLgak5PhOWH3XJteO0BYSWfPXzDbdxKjEuHwEQ9Ng?e=XK72xS

Comment: this is how the address fields look with the code, it just produces more fields https://neonschwarz-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/f_pernleitner_bretz-austria_at/Ef-ZDJgWRiJAhz5EuvsMc4YBtRPcSQCkLLgMkbE4NxSC7w?e=G73BCH

Comment: Try using 
if( isset($address_fields['billing_email'] ) {
                unset($address_fields['billing_email']);
            }
instead of $address_fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found out what the problem is, I have to return the fields also when there is no product with the tag id 199, thank you for helping me think about the problem :-)

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'schwinn_validation' , 10, 1);
    function schwinn_validation( $address_fields ) {
$schwinn_cart=WC()->cart->get_cart();


    foreach( $schwinn_cart as $cart_item ){

        $product_array = $cart_item['data'];

        //echo $product_array->tag_ids[0];
        $product_tags_incart=$product_array->tag_ids[0];

        // wenn das Produkt mit tag id 199 getagt ist, werden die Rechnungsadressenfelder ausgeblendet, weil das Produkt dann eine Kundenrechnung ist
            if($product_tags_incart == 199 ){

        $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_first_name']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_last_name']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_city']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = false;
        $address_fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;

        return $address_fields;
    
        }else{
                return $address_fields;
            };

    }
    }
```